# Getting esFactory not a a function

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I am new to `elasticsearch` with `angularjs` and I am trying to integrate `elasticsearch` with angular. I am getting the following error: "esFactory not a a function".
I have not installed `node.js`. Is it required ??
Below is my code:

```
var EsConnectorApp=angular.module('elasticsearchtest',['elasticsearch']);

EsConnectorApp.service('es',[function(esFactory){
    return esFactory({
        host:'localhost:9200'
    });

}]);

EsConnectorApp.controller('ServerHealthController', function($scope, es) {

    es.cluster.health(function (err, resp) {
        if (err) {
            $scope.data = err.message;
        } else {
            $scope.data = resp;
        }
    });
});
```

I am using two angular libs:

- angular.min.js
- elasticsearch.angular.js

I get the error:

```
esFactory not a a function
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your controller like this and it works:

```
var EsConnectorApp= angular.module('elasticsearchtest', ['elasticsearch']);
EsConnectorApp.service('es',function(esFactory) {
    return esFactory({
        host: 'localhost:9200'
    });

});
EsConnectorApp.controller('ServerHealthController', ['$scope', 'es', function($scope, es) {
    console.log('working');
    es.cluster.health(function(err, resp) {
        if (err) {
            $scope.data = err.message;
        } else {
            $scope.data = resp;
        }
    });

}]);
```

I removed the '[' when defining the service and that remove the error. From EsConnectorApp.service('es',[function( ... ]); to EsConnectorApp.service('es', function (...) );

My HTML includes:

```
<script src="node_modules/elasticsearch-browser/elasticsearch.angular.min.js"></script>
```